# Streaming Dataflow job throws gRPC error from the worker

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, grpc, apache-beam

My streaming dataflow job (from Pub/Sub source) throws multiple error messages from the worker:

```
Failed to read inputs in the data plane. Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/data_plane.py", line 581, in _read_inputs for elements in elements_iterator: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 416, in __next__ return self._next() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 706, in _next raise self grpc._channel._MultiThreadedRendezvous: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with: status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE details = "keepalive watchdog timeout" debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1619783831.069194941","description":"Error received from peer ipv6:[::1]:12371","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1061,"grpc_message":"keepalive watchdog timeout","grpc_status":14}" >
```

which leads to another error message:

```
Python sdk harness failed: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker_main.py", line 155, in main SdkHarness( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 256, in run for work_request in self._control_stub.Control(get_responses()): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 416, in __next__ return self._next() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 689, in _next raise self grpc._channel._MultiThreadedRendezvous: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with: status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE details = "keepalive watchdog timeout" debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1619786284.366500317","description":"Error received from peer ipv6:[::1]:12371","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1061,"grpc_message":"keepalive watchdog timeout","grpc_status":14}" >
```

judging from "description":"Error received from peer ipv6:[::1]:12371","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc" line, it seems that for some reason, the job cannot reach the grpc backend of the dataflow service.

Is that correct or any other reason for that error message? I use Apache Beam SDK 2.28 for python 3.8. I also use VPC settings that set using --subnetwork=https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/.../regions/.../subnetworks/... pipeline option if that worth mentioning

Comment: The jobs I work on also throw from time to time these errors. The good thing is that the job is not getting stuck or something, but it's still annoying. I also have not found the reason of them.

Comment: I think the error is benign. gRPC sometimes times out and you get such logs: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/22963. Your work is always retried by Dataflow and gRPC also has some retry policies. So as long as your job is not stuck, it's not an issue.

Comment: @大ドア東 so the error comes from the google side of backend then? At one point it seems that the error hangs the job (system lag and data freshness keep increased) and I thought it correlates with the increases number of processed data. I also cap the max number of workers.

Comment: Yeah, it's from its backend or any dependency/IO (GCE, Pub/Sub). But it's not necessarily an RPC to a real remote service. Some SDK or dependency implementation might start in-process grpc server so that they can do things x-lang (expansion service) or manipulate streams through services defined as a proto (InteractiveRunner for streaming). But as long as the job is not stuck permanently (no consistent linear system/data latency increment), it should be fine. Also note if there is any announcement of outages. If the job is in a bad shape for no reason, contact the support for further triage.